# MariaDB 5.5.47 but cannot Install TokuDB

Tags: mariadb, centos, tokudb

This is on CentOS 7.1, 
`sudo yum install MariaDB-tokudb-engine` says there's no such package and if I try to start the server with `plugin-load=ha_tokudb` in `my.cnf` I get

```
[ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/ha_tokudb.so' (errno: 0, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[ERROR] Couldn't load plugins from 'ha_tokudb.so'.
```

in the error log (but the server starts OK)

It wasn't me who installed this MariaDB and I'm trying to enable/install TokuDB as it's best suited for the workload imo (or at least I have to try)

How do I install/enable TokuDB on this server? How to get that yum package installed for example if that's required in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to get the built in TokuDB was 'remove' mariadb, mariadb.server and reinstall it using the steps [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/upgrading-from-mariadb-55-to-mariadb-100/).

This setup even keeps the database files in a different dir rather than `/var/lib` and it still worked fine as long as you call `mysql_upgrade --socket=[your custom socked location]`